# Calling super() inside constructor of JavaScript ES6 class which extends Object

Tags: javascript, es6-class

In the following I'm trying to create a subclass of Object which behaves like Object does in terms of creating instances by using 'new'. I would of course add more methods to my subclass, but below shows the problem I have calling the super-constructor from within my constructor.

Why does an instance of my class Sub not have the field 'x' like a plain Object does when created in the same way with 'new' with the same argument?

```
class Sub extends Object
{ constructor (anObject)
  { super(anObject);
  }
}
var ob  = new Object ({x: 123} );
var sub = new Sub    ({x: 123} );
console.log( ob.x ); // -> 123
console.log( sub.x); // -> undefined
```

Answer (score 6):

Basically, because `Object` is special and plays by different rules, since it's pretty much the most foundational construct in JavaScript.

Instead of extending `Object`, just create it with no super class (since it'll be an Object anyways) and use `Object.assign(this, obj)` to assign all of the properties to the newly created object.

```js
class Sub {
  constructor(obj) {
    Object.assign(this, obj);
  }
}

console.log(new Object({a: 1}));
console.log(new Sub({a: 1}));
```

Comment: I agree that "Object is special" but I think it should be special in that other classes should inherit its behavior if they add none of their own.  I still wonder if this is actually a bug in the implementation, happens on Node v8.0.0.  Does anyone know if the spec actually says somewhere this is how it should work? Thanks

Comment: @PanuLogic some years have passed, but I only now stumbled over this question. I just wanted to add that the behavior is not restricted to Node, but that it's the same on recent browsers (Firefox 115 and Chromium 115). This makes it less probable that it's an implementation bug, but  I agree that it feels like one ...

Answer (score 0):

While I find this behavior confusing myself (and thus cannot answer the deeper "why it was designed like this"), it seems to be documented behavior. In [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Object) it says:

> When Object() is implicitly called via super() in the constructor of a class that extends Object, it initializes a new object with new.target.prototype as its prototype. Any value passed to super() is ignored — for example, even if you pass a number, the this value inside the constructor does not become a Number instance.

The [specs](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-object-value) say:

> This function performs the following steps when called:
>
> 1. If NewTarget is neither undefined nor the active function object, then
>    a. Return ? OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor(NewTarget, "%Object.prototype%").
> 2. If value is either undefined or null, return OrdinaryObjectCreate(%Object.prototype%).
> 3. Return ! ToObject(value).

To my understanding, while the last one is the one you get when calling `new Object(obj)`, you get the first one when calling `super(obj)`.

Thus the behavior is not only in Node, but also in all spec respecting browsers (I've verified in Firefox 115 and Chromium 115).